# In Chef, how do you notify a resource outside of a resource?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to create an `execute` resource which sets up some environment variables and calls a certain command. But this `execute` resource should just be a sort of "method", i.e. define some functionality that I can reuse later. I want to be able to trigger this `execute` from other recipes, and currently I am using a `ruby_block` although I have a feeling I am doing something wrong. (My cookbook is called `commands`)

This is my reusable functionality:

```
# default.rb

execute 'Run command' do
  Chef::Log.info("Running command: #{node['task']}")

  command node['task']
  cwd deploy[:current_path]
  environment (node[:task] || {})
  action :nothing
  not_if node[:task].nil?
end
```

And this is one of the specific tasks which utilises it:

```
# rake_db_migrate.rb

include_recipe 'commands'

node.set[:task] = 'rake db:migrate'

ruby_block 'Trigger command' do
  block {}
  notifies :run, 'execute[Run command]', :immediately    
end
```

I also want to be able to run this with arbitrary tasks by setting a property on the node, which is essentially the same as the above but without writing to `node['task']`:

```
# run.rb

include_recipe 'commands'

ruby_block 'Trigger command' do
  block {}
  notifies :run, 'execute[Run command]', :immediately    
end
```

Essentially I want to define some reusable functionality in `default.rb`, and then be able to use this from other recipes, like `run.rb` and `rake_db_migrate.rb`, is this the right way or am I missing something?

Comment: I'd say you want to use [definitions](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_definitions.html) or [libraries](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_libraries.html) for creating reusable functions.

Comment: Wrap it in a definition or LWRP

Comment: I used a definition in the end. If either of you wants to post that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you probably want to use a definition: http://docs.chef.io/definitions.html

define the reusable bits and use 'task' as a parameter.